# I'd like not exceed 30 insertions in my listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem doing it for a week I'm working on and I would love to find a solution ... it is a web application in asp.net and c #
I have a related listeview a database which I am inserting the students .. and I'd like not exceed 30 insertions ... the goal is that if I try to enter the 31th student I must be stopped displaying a warning message

I try Sev code which seems to me that here is the nearest that I put in my page load, but unfortunately its not working

```
if (ListView1.Items.Count>30)
{ 
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
     "myalert", 
     "alert('" + "Dsl .. étudiant !!" + "');", true);
}
```

Comment: Can you prove the code which you are using to insert in ListView. Are you using server side event to insert into ListView? And can you please check if the script you mentioned is being registered in the HTML page.

Comment: Hi,
I use SqlDataSource in my listview and I chose the automatic insertion options and I have a piece of code that works perfectly all what I would like now is to limit the number of records

Answer (score 0):

Note: All you have said in your problem description is "*...but unfortunately its not working*", so I don't know for sure what the problem is.  I'm assuming that you never actually make it inside the `if`-block.

You mention that the code in your question is in `Page_Load`.  Just to be safe, I would put it in the databound event of your `ListView`:

```
ListView1_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListView1.Items.Count>30)
    { 
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
         "myalert", 
         "alert('" + "Dsl .. étudiant !!" + "');", true);
    }
}
```

This way you know that your `ListView1.Items.Count` is correct and up-to-date.